# Changing CSS when scrolling (working in console and JSFiddle but not in my HTML?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I have some weird problem:

I want to change the text color of my menu when scrolling. It is working in **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lgd36oef/)** and in the console but not in my HTML...:

[image]

But changing the background when scrolling **DOES** work!

The thing is, that I need to override a style in SemanticUI that uses `!important` and I have to use `.querySelector().setAttribute()` instead of `.getElementById().style.color` because it seems to not support adding `!important` to a color.

[Here's the link to my project](http://www.ibex-consulting.de/kunden) (I hope npm forever will stay online long enough...)

Is there anything I'm missing?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the above answer by `@taras-d`, you have two elements with same id. If you want to change color of both elements means you need to get all elements and apply css to it.

```
var _activeElements = $(".nav_bar #activeItem");
_activeElements.each(function(index) {
    _activeElements[index].setAttribute('style', 'color: #744a84 !important');
});
```

Add some dummy class like `nav_bar` to upper element to select all elements

```
<div class="right menu nav_bar" id="rightMenu">
...
</div>
```

Add `nav_bar` class to another `#activeItem` parent element, then it will iterate to all elements and apply css

Comment: Thanks a lot! This helped me changing the colors of all menu items without much code! :)

Answer (score 4):

You have two elements with same id *#activeItem*

[image]

You need to update selector to select right item:

```js
document.querySelector('#dMenu #activeItem').setAttribute('style', 'color: #744a84 !important');
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked! Still, I wonder how there happen to be two elements with that ID... I'll vote you up as soon as I have enough reputation! :)